# MySQL column names as field names for a many to many relationship with a junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, pivot, pivot-table

bit of a complicated one here. I've been looking around at a way to use results as column names, and whilst it seems possible, all the examples I've found use a very simple table design.

What I've got is 3 tables.

We have an 'order' table, which can then have 'order_extras'. The 'extras' table stores the names and prices of the extras, and the 'order_extras' basically cointains a primary key, the order id and the extra id.

A rough graphical representation of this is as follows:[image]

Using this as an example, lets assume the 'extras' table is populated with 3 extra items, the name and price are irrelevant at this stage.

What I want to do, is get all the orders, but with extra columns for the name of each extra item. If the item has been purchased (aka linked in the order_extras table) it'll show the price, otherwise it'll be empty/null.

Is this even possible? I've been looking into pivot tables but the information on this sort of thing seems a bit shaky. Any info or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Example data**

Extras:

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| id |       name       | price  |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | Insurance        | 59.95  |
|  2 | Lifetime Updates | 79.95  |
|  3 | Phone Support    | 124.95 |
+----+------------------+--------+
```

Orders:

```
+----+------------+
| id |  customer  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | John Smith |
|  2 | Bob Newbie |
|  3 | Bill Jobs  |
|  4 | Ray Stantz |
+----+------------+
```

order_extras:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | order_id | extra_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        4 |        2 |
|  2 |        3 |        1 |
|  3 |        3 |        3 |
|  4 |        1 |        1 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----------+----------------+-----------+------------------+---------------+
| order.id | order.customer | Insurance | Lifetime Updates | Phone Support |
+----------+----------------+-----------+------------------+---------------+
|        1 | John Smith     | 59.95     | 0                | 0             |
|        2 | Bob Newbie     | 0         | 0                | 0             |
|        3 | Bill Jobs      | 59.95     | 0                | 124.95        |
|        4 | Ray Stantz     | 0         | 79.95            | 0             |
+----------+----------------+-----------+------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result? It might be easier to understand what you are doing without reading the word problem. :)

Comment: From what I Can tell, MySQL doesn't support any sort of pivot keyword or "true" pivoting at all.  Take a look at this post.  This guy wrote a crazy sproc to handle it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158230/mysql-pivot-table-with-dynamic-headers-based-on-single-column-data

Comment: Just updated the first post with some examples of what I'm hoping to do

Comment: There is a question like yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a *pivot* function, but is can be replicated using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

If you have a known number of `extras`, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select o.id,
  o.customer,
  max(case when e.name = 'Insurance' then e.price else 0 end) Insurance,
  max(case when e.name = 'Lifetime Updates' then e.price else 0 end) `Lifetime Updates`,
  max(case when e.name = 'Phone Support' then e.price else 0 end) `Phone Support`
from orders o
left join order_extras oe
  on o.id = oe.order_id
left join extras e
  on oe.extra_id = e.id
group by o.id, o.customer
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e0fa/2).

For your situation, it seems like you will have an unknown number of values.  If that is the case, then you will need to use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN e.name = ''',
      name,
      ''' THEN e.price else 0 END) AS `',
      name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM extras;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT o.id,
                o.customer, ', @sql, ' 
            from orders o
            left join order_extras oe
              on o.id = oe.order_id
            left join extras e
              on oe.extra_id = e.id
            group by o.id, o.customer');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e0fa/4).

Both of these versions will give the result:

```
| ID |   CUSTOMER | INSURANCE | LIFETIME UPDATES | PHONE SUPPORT |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | John Smith |     59.95 |                0 |             0 |
|  2 | Bob Newbie |         0 |                0 |             0 |
|  3 |  Bill Jobs |     59.95 |                0 |        124.95 |
|  4 | Ray Stantz |         0 |            79.95 |             0 |
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for that second example - thats spot on! I've tried running it via my local database, and the query runs successfully but doesn't actually return anything. Bit odd, its obviously working as its showing a row count, but there just aren't any results listed. Tried this in both phpMyAdmin and the mac app 'Sequel Pro' :/

Comment: It's strange - if I run it as a standard query it doesn't output anything. However thankfully I wanted to export it to CSV anyway. Using outfile, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

try this .

```
    select o.id , o.customer ,
    max(if(e.name = 'Insurance' , round(e.price,2), 0)) as Insurance,
    max(if(e.name = 'Lifetime Updates' , round(e.price,2), 0)) as Lifetime_Updates,
    max(if(e.name = 'Phone Support' , round(e.price,2), 0)) as Phone_Support

     from orders o
     left join order_extras oe
     on o.id = oe.order_id
    left join Extras e
    on oe.extra_id = e.id

    group by o.id, o.customer
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/881ad/20)

OUTPUT IS:

```
   ID   CUSTOMER    INSURANCE   LIFETIME_UPDATES    PHONE_SUPPORT
    1   John Smith   59.95              0                0
    2   Bob Newbie     0                0                0
    3   Bill Jobs    59.95              0              124.95
    4   Ray Stantz     0              79.95              0
```