# How to rotate records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns (A and B) in a table:

```
column_A      column_B
   10           alb
   13           clk
   22           mbr
```

I am looking for a solution which would return:

```
column_A        10      13     22
column_B        alb     clk    mbr
```

How can I achieve this?

I don't know the number of source rows - it will change dynamically.

Comment: Do you already know the number of rows of your original table or not? however it seems to me a typical problem that must be solved at application level.

Comment: look on pivot mysql in the site

Comment: Take a look even at this old thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826455/join-two-tables-with-a-1-m-relationship-where-the-second-table-needs-to-be-fla/5826533#5826533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "Pivot tables" section of this web page: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Comment: In general, thank you very much for your interest. I was looking just for some kind of solution using PIVOT, but, unfortunately, your suggestions were so vague that I did not find any simple indication for my problem. The web is a whole bunch of examples but not for this kind of problem. I solved the problem based on HTML - tables inside table:)) It is not very elegant but may be satisfactory. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Did you even read the link? What about http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78? Of course the resource was vague; there's not going to be an example on the Internet specifically for you problem. You're suppose to interpret it and apply the solution to your own problem; that's how you learn.