# How to use JOIN and avoid getting duplicate data?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: **projects**, **categories** and **projects_categories**.

I want to get the project name, description and categories but there can be more than one category per project so i am getting duplicate content using the next query:

```
SELECT projects.name, projects.description, categories.name
FROM projects
JOIN projects_categories ON projects.project_id = projects_categories.project_id
JOIN categories ON projects_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE projects.project_id = ?
```

I am getting this:

```
++ name +++   ++ description ++    ++ name (category) ++
project1      bla bla bla          film
project1      bla bla bla          music
```

As u can see im getting two rows instead of one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group_concat is the tag that you are looking for:

```
SELECT projects.name, 
       projects.description, 
       group_concat(categories.name SEPARATOR ' ') as category_name
FROM projects
JOIN projects_categories 
  ON projects.project_id = projects_categories.project_id
JOIN categories 
  ON projects_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE projects.project_id = ?
group by projects.name, projects.description
```

Comment: Great! But lets say I want to get each category separated? Is there a 'mysql way' or just use split() or something like that will be better?

Comment: @Jonathan - You pretty much need to use the equivalent of split() in your programming language, assuming that any project can be assigned to n categories.  If you limit the number of categories a project can belong to, you could hard code each of those categories into the query.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the categories and return a single row.

```
SELECT projects.name, projects.description, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name)
FROM projects
JOIN projects_categories ON projects.project_id = projects_categories.project_id
JOIN categories ON projects_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE projects.project_id = ?
GROUP BY projects.name, projects.description
```

Comment: Great! But lets say I want to get each category separated? Is there a 'mysql way' or just use split() or something like that will be better?

Comment: Separated as in separate columns in one row?

Comment: @Jonathan: See this Q&A for an example. [Join two tables (with a 1-M relationship) where the second table needs to be 'flattened' into one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826455/join-two-tables-with-a-1-m-relationship-where-the-second-table-needs-to-be-fl)