# How to return different kind of values in a column in one record

Tags: mysql

I have a table **dict** (id,dict_name,dict_id,dict_type) and table **record**(fruit_id,tool_id,lan_id).I need to query it and return three dict_name for the three given ids in **record** in one record.

For example

It will return three dict_name(apple,car,lisp when fruit_id = 100, tool_id = 1000, lan_id = 22222) when I use **limit 1** in the query,

I have tried lots ways to query, like

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(dict.dict_name))
 FROM dict
 JOIN record
 WHERE dict.dict_id IN (record.fruit_id, record.tool_id, record.lan_id)
 GROUP BY dict.type" //
```

But I only get one dict_name in every record,and dict_names in

```
{'group_concat(DISTINCT(dict.dict_name))': apple},
```

and thress dict_names  but in more than one records

```
{'group_concat(DISTINCT(dict.dict_name))': apple},
{'group_concat(DISTINCT(dict.dict_name))': car},
{'group_concat(DISTINCT(dict.dict_name))': lisp}
```

Thank you.

dict:

```
dict_name  //  dict_id  //  type

    apple  //      100  // fruit
     pear  //      101  // fruit
      car  //     1000  //  tool
      bus  //     1001  //  tool
     lisp  //    22222  //   lan
     perl  //    22223  //   lan
```

id_record

```
 fruit_id  //  tool_id  // lan_id

      100 //      1000  //  22222
      100  //     1000  //  22222
      100  //     1000  //  22223
      101  //     1001  //  22223
      101  //     1001  //  22223
      101  //     1001  //  22223
```

It seems [One-to-Many SQL SELECT into single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441305/one-to-many-sql-select-into-single-row) may help.

Comment: In the title you said SQL Server, but in your query it is MySQL as there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL Server. Which RDBMS you are working with? SQL Server or MySQL??

Comment: MySQL,sorry for that.

Comment: answered by @spencer7593 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441305/one-to-many-sql-select-into-single-row